# Как обстоят дела с безопасностью репозитория PyPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, безопасность

Вопрос давно уже волнует, теперь появился повод его задать.

Вот статья о том что какой-то школьник из Италии залил вредоносный код в виде библиотеки к Python.

[Ссылка на статью](https://safe.cnews.ru/news/top/2022-08-09_shkolnik_sozdal_tri_moshchnyh)

Неужели о безопасности пользователей этого ресурса никто не беспокоится?

В статье рассказывается не совсем о злоумышленнике, но ведь могут быть проблемы серьезнее.

Comment: Абсолютно любой человек может залить абсолютно любой код на PyPI. То же самое с NPM, Packagist, NuGet, crates.io и любыми другими репозиториями пакетов. Ответственность за безопасность лежит на тех, кто скачивает оттуда пакеты: просто не нужно ставить что попало.

Comment: Хорошо я может и не буду ставить что попало, но ведь некоторые пакеты тянут зависимости иногда честно сказать сомнительного производства.

Comment: Вообще я был уверен что этот вопрос кем то контролируется.

Comment: Что я могу допустим сделать более удобную обёртку для популярной библиотеки, зашить код для слежения за пользователем (запись действий) и об этом ни кто не узнает?

Comment: Все может быть. Любой пакет (или его зависимость) может стать скомпрометированным, как вот недавно история с пакетом "ctx". Так что безопасность опирается исключительно на "авось пронесёт"

Comment: М-да, меня это озадачило.

Comment: "зашить код" - и делают так даже без компрометации. После начала известных событий в Украине некоторые авторы вшили в свои пакеты то, чему там не место. Я так попал с пакетом "finplot". Приходится после установки лезть и руками удалять лишний код.

Answer (score 2):

### Безопасность PyPI

Каталог PyPI служит источником информации для систем обновления программного обеспечения на Python, что неизбежно ставит вопрос обеспечения информационной безопасности. Система управления библиотеками Python позволяет не доверяющим друг другу (англ. mutually distrustful) разработчикам делать свои библиотеки доступными пользователям. В настоящее время в PyPI отсутствует механизм защиты обнаружения обновлений (англ. update discovery) и процесса установки, но существует TUF (англ. The Update Framework) — прототип каркаса для безопасной работы с PyPI посредством утилиты `easy_install`.

---

### Немного о easy_install

Несколько лет назад у easy_install были преимущества, например pip не поддерживал установки бинарников, а теперь поддерживает. Формат бинарников для pip - Wheels, пришедший на замену формату Egg, работающему с easy_install. Также pip стал поддерживать установку из систем контроля версий через префиксы "git+", "hg+", "bzr+", "svn+", например: `pip install git+https://github.com/fact-project/smart_fact_crawler`. На сегодняшний день преимуществ у easy_install почти нет.

---

### [safety](https://pypi.org/project/safety/)

### [safety 2 doc](https://docs.pyup.io/docs/getting-started-with-safety-cli)

Проверяет зависимости Python на наличие известных уязвимостей безопасности и предлагает надлежащие исправления для обнаруженных уязвимостей.

Safety 2 — это следующая версия нашего ведущего в отрасли сканера зависимостей Python. Safety 2 — лучший способ проверить ваши зависимости Python на наличие уязвимостей безопасности и других рисков соответствия.

---

### [Bandit](https://pypi.org/project/bandit/)

Инструмент, предназначенный для поиска распространенных проблем безопасности в коде Python. Для этого Bandit обрабатывает каждый файл, строит из него AST и запускает соответствующие плагины для узлов AST. Как только Bandit завершит сканирование всех файлов, он создаст отчет.

### [Snyk Advisor](https://snyk.io/advisor/)

Проверка на популярность\безопасность желаемого пакета.

---

### [Предотвращение атак с путаницей зависимостей в Python](https://medium.com/ochrona/preventing-dependency-confusion-attacks-in-python-fa6058ac972f)

Статья о том как злоумышленники используют сочетание общедоступных и частных пакетов.

Несколько пунктов из статьи о том как это можно предотвратить:

1. Используйте закрепление зависимостей
2. Используйте хеширование зависимостей
3. Удалите использование --extra-index-url аргумента pip.

Подробнее в статье по ссылке.

> Обязательно ознакомьтесь с бесплатными инструментами `SCA`, такими как
> `Ochrona`, и инструментами `SAST`, такими как `bandit` , чтобы встроить
> дополнительные средства защиты в свои процессы разработки.

### Источники:

[PyPI - Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyPI)

[pip или easy_install](https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/pip-vs-easy_install)

[Сообщение о проблеме безопасности PyPI](https://pypi.org/security/)(что делать при обнаружении)

[Шпаргалка по лучшим практикам безопасности Python](https://snyk.io/blog/python-security-best-practices-cheat-sheet/)

[Устранение путаницы в цепочке эксплойтов зависимостей](https://discuss.python.org/t/addressing-dependency-version-confusion-exploit-chain/7143/21)(Обсуждение о проблеме)